# StatsModels formula Polynomial Regression does not match numpy polyfit coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, regression, statsmodels, non-linear-regression

My polynomial regression using statsmodels formula does not match nupy polyfit coefficients.

Link to data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQuCoCF_TeXzZuUFyKaHCbD1zle2f1MF/view?usp=sharing

Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

data = pd.read_csv('sp500.csv')

data['Date_Ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']).apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())

x = data['Date_Ordinal']
y = data['Value']

np.polyfit(x,y,2)

model = smf.ols(formula='y ~ x + I(x**2)', data = data).fit()
model.summary()
```

**Numpy polyfit coefficient results:**

array([ 4.17939013e-05, -6.09338454e+01,  2.22098809e+07])

**Statsmodels coefficient results:**

x**2: 7.468e-07

x: -0.5466

Intercept: -1.486e-06

When I add a quadratic trend line to the data in Excel, Excel results coincide with the numpy coefficients. However, if I add an intercept of 1 to the Excel trend line, the coefficients for x**2 and x equal the statsmodels coefficients but the excel intercept becomes 1 where as the statsmodels intercept is -1.486e-06.

If remove the intercept from the statsmodels formula by subtracting 1,all it does is remove the intercept altogether from statsmodels results but the coefficients remain the same.

How can I get statsmodels to show the same coefficient results as numpy polyfit and Excel?

Comment: This could be a numerical problem because of bad scaling. What's the range of your `x` dates? What condition number does statsmodels report in OLS?

Comment: Range of x dates is 1/1/2010 to 12/1/2019 (monthly frequency) . Condition number is 2.95e+17. Does this explain why the coefficients match between numpy and excel(without intercept) and between statsmodels and excel(with intercept at 1)?

Comment: does your data have only two columns? as your feeding data in `smf.ols()`

Comment: Data originally has Date column and Value column but then I add a Date_Ordinal column

Comment: rescale your Date_Ordinal to have some small numbers. Your condition number essentially means that the computation are numerically unstable, so the numbers are driven my numerical noise which might be the same if the same underlying numerical functions are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomials can become very badly scaled if the underlying data is not in a small range around zero. 
As a consequence, computation become numerically unstable and the results can be dominated by numerical noise.

http://jpktd.blogspot.com/2012/03/numerical-accuracy-in-linear-least.html
looks at a NIST test case with polynomials that are very badly scaled and many statistics packages cannot produce a numerically stable solution.

Numpy's polynomial fitting can internally rescale the variables before creating the polynomial basis function.

Generic regression models like OLS in statsmodels do not have the necessary information to rescale the underlying variables to improve numerical stability. Besides, scaling and handling multicollinearity is left to the decisions of the user. 
OLS summary should have printed a warning in this case.